# How do I seperate three lights from 1 switch?

Tags: electrical

I have one light switch that controls 3 lights - how do I separate that switch to two individual switches?

Comment: What would the two switches control?  Do wires from each light come back to the switch box?  Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do this, is if the wires feeding each light came all the way back to the switch. Which is not a common wiring method, so not a likely situation.

In any case, without more information, a more accurate answer cannot be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Without rewiring, the only suggestion I can offer is home-automatioN hardware. Leave the existing swithc as it is, install remote-control adapters in the lamps, hang the control panel next to the existing switch and manage the separate groups from there.

Some LED bulbs now have remote control receivers built into them. This is a convenient, but moderately expensive, solution.